# US tax question, sold foreign stock and after some time repatriated the money. How do I handle currency fluctuations?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, currency, schedule-d

I, a US citizen sold some foreign stocks. But could repatriate the money to US after a while. In that time the currency moved substantially. How do I account for currency fluctuations? My Schedule D will have capital gains/losses for the stock. Can I add currency trade too to the Schedule D to account for the currency value change?